# Can I use drawables in Wear OS Tiles?

Tags: wear-os, tile

I'm going through the Tiles Codelab:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/wear-tiles

I want to use drawables instead of url in the tile layout.

i replace the url with drawable (for example: "R.drawable.ic_search_24")
but i see a blank circle. What is happening?

In the MessagingTileRender.kt (module)

```
private fun contactLayout(
    context: Context,
    contact: Contact,
    clickable: ModifiersBuilders.Clickable,
) = Button.Builder(context, clickable)
    .setContentDescription(contact.name)
    .apply {
        if (contact.avatarUrl != null) {
            //se c'è un link recupera l'immagine
            setImageContent(R.drawable.ic_search_24.toString())
            //setImageContent(contact.imageResourceId())
            //mettere qui il recupero dell'immagine
        } else {
            setTextContent(contact.initials)
            //altrimenti prende le iniziali e li mette colorate come bottone
            setButtonColors(ButtonColors.secondaryButtonColors(MessagingTileTheme.colors))
        }
    }
    .build()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of the tag information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title contains nothing useful or meaningful at all.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for trying the codelab.

Tiles can't use drawables directly like this. In your layout, it's necessary to pass a string ID (it's not a url).

In `onResourcesRequested()` (or similar), you must map that ID to an ImageResource (which can be created from a drawable), as in the codelab.

Check out the `finished` module for an example.